# Navigate to 2 differents screens after Submit()

Tags: powerapps

I want to navigate in differents screens after the user submits a Form. When a user choose the radio button A => navigate to screen A and with radio button B => navigate to screen B.

My formula looks like this :

If(SubmitForm(Form1),If(DataCardValue2.Selected.Value="A",Navigate(ScreenA),Navigate(ScreenB)))

What do I miss? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this on your button OnSelect, use your form's "OnSuccess" property

> OnSuccess : If(Self.LastSubmit.[Col name] = "A", Navigate(Screen1) , Navigate(Screen2) )

Good day,

Comment: Thanks for replying but I have a form with many columns. Do you have another approach? And I wish you a good day too :)

Comment: How the number of columns can impact ? Your form is on multiple screens ? 

Or you can use a context variable "varScreen" that you can update when your DataCardValues change and finish with a "Navigate(varScreen)" where you want

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I was confused about the syntax. It works now. Thank you :)