# PowerApps App with Excel data source - Debug

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I'm new to PowerApps and coding and don't know how to debug my first PowerApp. I've googled and youtubed but no.

I don't even know how to get the code to stackoverflow so you can help me.

The app collect data in Screen1(Form1)

then collects lat long time data in Screen2(Form1) and when a button is clicked Submit(Form1) and Navigate(Screen3)

then collects another set of lat long time data in Screen3(Form1) ,writes it to Form1 when a button is clicked and 'here lies the issue' Navigate(Form2). For some or other reason it gets stuck with this step. Data in Excel seems ok but can't get it to submit the next record with all the same data except for lat long time values.

Here is the code I used in the OnSelect box of Button(Screen3);

```
<Set(LatUnload,Location.Latitude);
 Set(LongUnload,Location.Longitude);
 Set(UnloadTime,Now());

 SubmitForm(EditForm1);

 Navigate(LoadScreen)>
```

I've downloaded the .msapp file and a app package (.zip) but don't know what is needed from the files to post here to help fixing the issue.

Appreciate your help and time

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar question here:
[Navigate to 2 differents screens after Submit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71568570/navigate-to-2-differents-screens-after-submit)

Basically, you need to put your Navigate(LoadScreen) into the OnSuccess property of your form